# How to Append and Prepend element in react js like jquery

Tags: reactjs, dom-manipulation

Is there any append, Prepend and toggle functions available in reactjs like functions available in jQuery. If not how to do that.

And also, Is there any tutorials or live online classes available for reactjs other than http://facebook.github.io/react/?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you tell us what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to perform append a HTML element on Click after an element in react js Example: 
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
});  I want to code for the same functionality in react js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a React way. Instead, you can render your components conditionally based on your state and props:

```
render: function(){
   var conditionalComponent = this.state.needToDisplayAdditionalText ? <b>Appended text</b> : null;
   return (
       <p>
            {conditionalComponent}
       </p>
   );
```

}